# How to determine which SSL library MySQL is using?

Tags: mysql, ssl, debian-squeeze

My Debian squeeze server is running mysqld version 5.1. How do I determine if the SSL libraries it is using are OpenSSL or yaSSL?

(I am pretty sure this MySQL supports SSL as the User table has the `ssl_type` column.)

Comment: What OS?  If GNU/Linux, which distro?

Comment: It is on Debian squeeze (I will update my question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run LDD on the MySql executable to see what it is linked against.

```
#ldd mysqld
```

Comment: This does not always work. I've got a TLS-enabled MySQL server but `ldd` reveals no hints about which library might be in use. (`pthread`, `aio`, `z`, `rt`, `wrap`, `crypt`, `dl`, `stdc++`, `m`, `gcc_s`, `c`, `nsl`). Perhaps the key is that `libdl` is in there, and so MySQL can dynamically-load anything it wants at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know from within MySQL you can check the status variable **Rsa_public_key** as
it only exists in builds with OpenSSL:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Rsa_public_key';
```

(See the relevant documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Rsa_public_key)

PS: Currently, the MySQL Community Edition binaries built by MySQL are using yaSSL, but e.g. Percona XtraDB Cluster binaries are built using OpenSSL. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
ldd `which mysqld`|grep ssl
```

it will show that your MySQL is linked to witch SSL library.

Comment: Unfortunately, that command yielded nothing.

Comment: Then maybe your MySQL not compiled with SSL support, check out 3rd section here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/configuring-for-ssl.html try

Comment: That was a good suggestion; it seems that my MySQL supports SSL but the `have_ssl` variable is `DISABLED`; I think there is something wrong with my MySQL installation or binary.

Comment: I got MySQL to work with SSL but there are no libraries linked in with mysqld that match `ssl`,

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://xn.pinkhamster.net/blog/tech/mysql_with_ssl_on_debian.html), the MySQL packages in Debian don't include TLS support due to licensing issues. That post is fairly old, but based on the [mysql-server-core-5.1 package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/mysql-server-core-5.1) not having a dependency on OpenSSL or GnuTLS I suspect that this is still true.

Comment: TLS support is currently built-into Debian 7 (Wheezy) packages for MySQL 5.5. It's possible that prior packages included such support as well. Both my `have_openssl` and `have_ssl` flags are `YES`.